# Importing multiple modules and importing classes from modules

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to make a pdf with python using pyFPDF, I want the date to be automatic and am trying to use the datetime module with the fpdf module but im getting an error.

tried
 import datetime, fpdf
then, 
 from fpdf import FPDF
get error.

also
 import datetime
then, 
 from fpdf import FPDF
error again,

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days= 1)
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days= 1)

from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=today, ln=1, align="C")
pdf.output("simple_demo_test88  .pdf")
```

I want todays date to show up written in the pdf,

but get a long error ending in :
 TypeError: object of type 'datetime.date' has no len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with modules: the `txt` argument of `cell` probably expects a `str` argument. Try passing `str(today)`:

```py
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=str(today), ln=1, align="C")

>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today()
datetime.date(2019, 7, 3)
>>> str(datetime.date.today())
'2019-07-03'
```

Comment: that was super fast, thank you so much it works now

Comment: @Electric_Print No problem!